# Как равномерно распределить N точек на M зон?

Tags: алгоритм, геометрия, любой-язык, кластеризация

Дано двумерное пространство. Даны N точек с заданными координатами. Нужно распределить точки в M зон. В каждую зону нужно поместить количество точек равное целому частному M/N или M/N+1. Способ определения кому достанется M/N, а кому M/N+1 значения не имеет. Внешний контур зон должен быть выпуклым. Зоны не должны пересекаться, а если это невозможно, то в пересечении зон, не должно быть внутренних точек.

Например,

[image: пример]

Следующий вариант плохой
[image: пример нежелательного решения]

Я затрудняюсь перенести это условие на формальный язык. В реальной задаче (N>5000, M~50) вариант с красными стрелками не подходит, потому что для "коммивояжеров" получится слишком неудобный участок

---

#### Похожие вопросы

- [Поиск геометрического центра группы объектов в 3D пространстве с предварительной фильтрацией](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/480368)
- [Какой существует алгоритм для объединения точек в области?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/524772)
- [Структура данных для упорядочения двумерных точек](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/543810)

#### Ссылки по теме

- [Хабрахабр. Андрей Часовских @andreycha. Обзор алгоритмов кластеризации данных.](https://habrahabr.ru/post/101338)

Comment: Отсортировать по координате x и поделить на M полос :) Зоны выпуклые, не пересекаются... Формально - условия выполнены.

Comment: @Harry  В каждую зону нужно поместить количество точек равное целому частному M/N или M/N+1

Comment: @Harry, спасибо за замечание. Конечно полоски не устроят (: а как это сформулировать?

Comment: а почему полоски не устроят?) только змейкой идти надо снизу вверх потом сверху вниз

Comment: @pavel, пока сам не понял почему...

Comment: @4per ... минимизируя максимальный диаметр выпуклой оболочки зоны. Так они будут более-менее равномерными, но эта задача на 99.99999% будет поддаваться только исчерпывающему перебору...

Comment: @Harry полный перебор совсем грустно, у меня в реальной задаче будет N>5000

Comment: Уточните вопрос, есть ли еще дополнительные условия и ограничения. Почему второй пример не подходит?

Comment: @Cerbo, дело в том, что я затрудняюсь перенести это условие на формальный язык. В реальной жизни (N>5000, M~50) вариант с красными стрелками не подходит, потому что для *"комивояжеров"* получится слишком неудобный участок.

Comment: То есть точки в зоне должны образовывать кластер? Если так, то что в приоритете выпуклость, непересекаемость или кластеры?

Comment: @Cerbo в приоритете близость точек друг к другу и равное количество для каждой зоны

Answer (score 10):

Точное решение с доказательством я привести не могу, но могу дать несколько направлений.

**Первый вариант**

Можно построить частный случай Kd-дерева, когда каждой области принадлежит по 1 точке, а после начать объединять области снизу, используя данное условие. Если точки находятся "близко", то они будут соседями на соседних уровнях, и поэтому объединятся в первую очередь.

**Второй вариант**

Второй вариант предполагает построение диаграммы Вороного. Для каждой точки находим ближайшие границы. Области можно объединять только с областями, которые смежные с данными границами. В данном случае будет усеченный перебор, так как в среднем у каждой точки будет мало таких границ. Худший случай - точки расположены строго по гексагональной сетке.

[image: Пример диаграммы Вороного]

Рекомендую посмотреть "Mark de Berg - Computational Geometry Algorithms and Applications". Там будет описание построения данных структур.

---

Я бы начал с первого варианта, так как Kd деревья реализуются достаточно просто и информации по ним больше, возможно, даже можно найти пример с объединением по условию, так как эти деревья имеют много применений. Диаграммы Вороного проще "дебажить" графически и есть много реализаций на разных языках, поэтому базу можно быстрее сделать.

Если отталкиваться от "в приоритете близость точек друг к другу и равное количество для каждой зоны", то диаграммы Вороного могут быть лучше, так как у них при построении похожая задача стоит. Возможно, можно доказать транзитивность этого условия между областями. Тогда достаточно будет построить диаграмму второго порядка, их в книге вроде нет, но можно найти несколько статей на эту тему. К сожалению, готовых реализаций для диаграмм высших порядков я не встречал, поэтому придется писать самостоятельно.

Comment: вы можете добавить минусы и плюсы приведенных вариантов, чтобы можно было решить с чего начать? хотя бы как предположения...

Comment: Я бы начал с первого варианта, так как Kd деревья реализуются достаточно просто и информации по ним больше, возможно, даже можно найти пример с объединением по условию, так как эти деревья имеют много применений. Диаграммы Вороного проще "дебажить" графически и есть много реализаций на разных языках, поэтому базу можно быстрее сделать.

Comment: Если отталкиваться от "в приоритете близость точек друг к другу и равное количество для каждой зоны", то диаграммы Вороного могут быть лучше, так как у них при построении похожая задача стоит. Возможно, можно доказать транзитивность этого условия между областями. Тогда достаточно будет построить диаграмму второго порядка, их в книге вроде нет, но можно найти несколько статей на эту тему. К сожалению, готовых реализаций для диаграмм высших порядков я не встречал, поэтому придется писать самостоятельно.

Answer (score 8):

Во-первых, замечу, что выпуклость контуров сама по себе не имеет смысла. Потому как контур любого кластера будет выпуклым. Требование выпуклости нужно для определения пересечений.

Вам для кластеризации подойдет алгоритм нечеткой кластеризации c-means, который является модификацией алгоритма k-means. Им обоим для работы требуется заранее знать количество кластеров для поиска, а это как раз ваш случай. Но у c-means есть то преимущество, перед k-means, что он для каждой точки дает нечеткую оценку принадлежности к кластерам.

Оценку пересечений нужно так же сделать нечеткой. То есть нужно знать насколько сильно пересекаются кластеры.

Далее, можно попробовать несколько эвристик:

1. Модифицировать c-means так, что в случае когда точка "близка" одновременно нескольким кластерам учитывать пересечение контуров, то есть "приближать" точку к тому кластеру который "уменьшает" пересечение.
2. Попробовать уменьшить пересечения за счет обмена "близкими" точками между пересекающимся кластерами. Если кластеры пересекаются, то велика вероятность что и другие их точки также "близки", чем точки из других кластеров.
3. Чтобы уменьшить пересечение нужно найти "виновников" пересечения и опробовать их забрать\отдать. При этом если в одном кластере будет нехватать точек, то в другом будет из избыток. Чтобы этого избежать можно забирать или отдавать точки любым кластерам к которым эти точки близки. В результате возникнет волна обменов, ее нужно остановливать если оценки пересечений начинают ухудшаться.
4. Так же как и в предыдущем варианте, но попробовать направлять волны обменов друг на друга чтобы они погасились. То есть волну "изъятия" нужно направлять на волну "отдающуюю".
5. Для алгоритма k-means очень важен выбор первоначальных центров кластеров. В случае если в какой-то области получилось много пересечений, то можно перестартовать k-means, приблизив первоначальные центы к пересечениям чтобы они поглотились новыми кластерами. При этом рестарт необязательно выполнять для всех точек, если другие кластеры далено от проблемного места их можно не трогать.